# Differentiate wrt the initial point

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, control-theory

Consider the control system 
$$
\dot x(t) = f(x(t),u(t))
$$
where $x(.)$ takes its values in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u$ takes its values in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f$ is a smooth vector field.
For $T>0$, denote $x(.;x_0)$ the trajectory defined on $[0,T]$ starting from $x_0$ at $t=0$.

For an admissible trajectory $x(.),u(.)$, the cost is defined by
$$
g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
$$
z\mapsto   \int_0^T L(x(s;z),u(s)) ds
$$
where $L:\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^m$ is smooth.

Assume $g'(z)$ exists, how to compute it ?
Should I considered a topology on a set of curves ?